# Not able to Set Background Image for RelativeLayout using Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

I am trying to set the Background Image for `RelativeLayout` using Java. The code compiles correctly, but I am not able to view the image on device. However, when I set the image using xml file, I can view it correctly. What might be the issue? See the xml file here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper1"> // background line
```

Java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mainView = (View) findViewById(R.id.root); 
    mainView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wallpaper1);
    // mainView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper1));
```

I have even tried using the second way commented above using `setBackground`, but that doesn't display the image. I thought it might be an image loading problem. But when I try to change the color instead of changing the image using Java the same thing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: R u sure its like `@drawable.wallpaper1`

Comment: the image is provided for each resolution?

Comment: android:background="@drawable/wallpaper1" use this

Comment: use android:background="@drawable/wallpaper1" on xml and check if its still appearing. if not then check if your image exists or in valid format

Comment: @StefanBeike what this have to do with resolution?

Comment: I got similar problems becouse I didnt provide images for the different resolution folders.

Comment: The image is provided for each resolution. Yes, the actual code in xml was @drawable/wallpaper1. The thing is xml is working correctly, however when I remove the background from xml and try to set it using the Java code it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sigma - Cast it to `RelativeLayout` instead of `View` here `mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);` and then set background

Comment: @KaranMer : tried using the Relative Layout approach. Still, the background image doesn't change. It just shows the default white background.